# How to feed random numbers as indices to pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a random sample from two pandas frames. If rows (random) 2,5,8 are selected in frame A, then the same 2,5,8 rows must be selected from frame B. I did it by first generating a random sample and now want to use this sample as indices for rows for frame. How can I do it? The code should look like

```
idx = list(random.sample(range(X_train.shape[0]),5000))

lgstc_reg[i].fit(X_train[idx,:], y_train[idx,:])
```

However, running the code gives an error.

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: Really long output: TypeError: and then probably the list of all indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iloc`:

```
indexes = [2,5,8]  # in your case this is the randomly generated list
A.iloc[indexes]
B.iloc[indexes]
```

An alternative consistent sampling methodology would be to set a random seed, and then sample:

```
random_seed = 42
A.sample(3, random_state=random_seed)
B.sample(3, random_state=random_seed)
```

The sampled DataFrames will have the same index.

Comment: Thanks! For the iloc case: how do you fix the random seed for each draw of indices (for reproducibility)?

Comment: If you're using the `random` library, you can call `random.seed(42)` (or any number) above your usage of `random.sample(...)`

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: Nice........!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
>>> df1
   value  ID
0      3   2
1      4   2
2      7   8
3      8   8
4     11   8
>>> df2
   value  distance
0      3         0
1      4         0
2      7         1
3      8         0
4     11         0
```

I have two data frames. I want to select randoms of `df1` along with corresponding rows of `df2`.

First I create a `sample_index` which a list of random rows of `df` using Pandas inbuilt function `sample`. Now use this index to location these rows in `df1` and `df2` with the help of another inbuilt funciton `loc`.

```
>>> selection_index = df1.sample(2).index
>>> selection_index
Int64Index([3, 1], dtype='int64')
>>> df1.loc[selection_index]
   value  ID
3      8   8
1      4   2
>>> df2.loc[selection_index]
   value  distance
3      8         0
1      4         0
>>>
```

In your case, this would become somewhat like

```py
idx = X_train.sample(5000).index

lgstc_reg[i].fit(X_train.loc[idx], y_train.loc[idx])
```